# Angular Table with expandable rows, subscribe and get data on expand row

Tags: html, angular, typescript, subscribe

I have requirement of getting data over http upon expanding the row of mat-table because of the data size. I have tried multiple solutions and nothing seems to work.
Would be glad if someone could help me out.

```html
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)= "onClick(expandedElement, element)"  >
  </tr>
```

Comment: How you want it exactly is not  clear. You want to display extra data in div when row clicked or show extra columns in table ?

Comment: Once the row is expanded, I want some other data to be displayed which i have to get it from an endpoint. Basically I have fetched the data that is needed to render the table.After that i need more data to be loaded onClick of each row. onClick function triggers a http call.